# Google drive deleting my gsheet files by itself

Tags: google-drive

I have not opened or deleted any of my files on Google Drive, however from time to time I see a number of my gsheet files in my trash folder. When I click on the googledrive icon it shows files synced and deleted, but I did not ask it to delete, how is it deleting files without me doing anything? Is my account compromised or is it a quirk of Google Drive? Is there anyway I can avoid such deletion of my files?

Comment: Are you syncing to one or more computers? If so, did you delete any of the .gsheet files there? Are any of the files or folders shared?